# How is trending coins or stocks calculated? What is the formula or metric used to define "top 10 trending coins or stocks today"?

Tags: stock-market, markets, price, cryptocurrency

We can see the [top 10 trending coins today](https://coinmarketcap.com/trending-cryptocurrencies/) in Coinmarketcap, Coingecko, etc. The same goes for stocks. So, how is it calculated? They're obviously taking multiple factors into consideration - total market cap, 24 hour trading volume, 7 day price change percentage, etc. But how do they all come together to define the trend is what I want to know.

For example, one straightforward idea might be to sort in descending order by the price percentage change in the last 24 hours, or 1 week. But that obviously yields a totally different "top 10" list that what's published by CMC in the link above. So I wonder, what are some ways in which we can define "trending"?

Answer (score 0):

Each platform uses different metrics to determine their top trending coins.

The main key metrics are:
Number of search
Number of tags on popular social media or within the platfrom
Change in price
Change in Volume

If you check the top cryptos in different platforms will get different top 10, due to the fact that some platforms will also consider the amount of times these cryptos are searched and tagged within that platform.

For instance in the link you provided, they specified that those the top most searched coins in coinmarketcap.com thus the metric they are using to obtain the trending is the amount of searches in coinmarketcap.com